# ECS: Dynamically create specific Object from Classname

Tags: java, reflection

I am looking to create a specific type of `Component` based on a `String` in an XML-file.

This can be done with

```
clazzName = "NameComponent";
Class.forName("my.package.x.y.z." + clazzName).newInstance();
```

In the application I am looping through a list of `clazzNames`.

However, this gets pretty complicated once param-constructors come into play. Especially if everything is stored in XML files.

Is there a cleaner method without having to give the package information and without having to worry about constructor arguments?

I am open for suggestions on different technologies than XML, if that lets me use proper parameters and does not need package information of the class.

Answer (score 0):

After compilation, the package is part of the class name. If you don't know the package, then you don't know the class name. What if there are two classes with the same "short name" in two different packages?

And if there are constructor arguments, then you *cannot* create an instance without passing values for them.